# Why Xcode does not search for file in subdirectory?

Tags: xcode

I got this error after a merge:

```
ERROR: Can't find /Users/kukodajanos/Workspace L/PFB2/crossfeed_connecting.png
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/copypng failed with exit code 1
```

**File is located not in root of the project but as it is usual in a subfolder, in `../PFB`.**

I set for all search path setting the subfolder, do not know what I still missing. Any idea?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your search path setting, choose the `recursive` option:

[image]